# Virtual Serial Device in Python?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, virtual-serial-port

I know that I can use e.g. pySerial to talk to serial devices, but what if I don't have a device right now but still need to write a client for it? How can I write a "virtual serial device" in Python and have pySerial talk to it, like I would, say, run a local web server? Maybe I'm just not searching well, but I've been unable to find any information on this topic.

Answer (score 56):

this is something I did and worked out for me so far:

```
import os, pty, serial

master, slave = pty.openpty()
s_name = os.ttyname(slave)

ser = serial.Serial(s_name)

# To Write to the device
ser.write('Your text')

# To read from the device
os.read(master,1000)
```

If you create more virtual ports you will have no problems as the different masters get different file descriptors even if they have the same name.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. This works for me on Mac OS X.

Comment: This will not work on Windows, which lacks the termios module required by pty.

Comment: I seem to be able to read from the fake device just fine (i.e. I have another program writing to the device at endpoint `s_name`), but whenever I issue `ser.write("...")`, that text just get echoed back the next time I `os.read(master,1000)`, regardless of if anything's connected to the port, and the other end of the port doesn't seem to get the data.

Comment: When I run your code in Ubuntu 14.04 I get the following error:
  `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 311, in open
    self._update_dtr_state()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 605, in _update_dtr_state
    fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCMBIS, TIOCM_DTR_str)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: Sorry Samuel, it works for me just fine right now. But I've since long ago stopped working on that project so I have not much input to give you at this point

Comment: @OYRM do you have some suggestions for Windows, I created question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36115831/programmatically-create-virtual-serial-port-on-windows

Comment: @SamuelGóngora, I was receiving the same error, make sure you have permissions to access the `/dev/tty` file by either running python with sudo, or changing ownership to the file to you.

Comment: @SamuelGóngora  Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831131/pyserial-does-not-play-well-with-virtual-port , I think this is probably the more accurate cause of the problem.

Comment: pyserial's unit tests have a nice set of examples: https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/7bd427087857ba474180058b727578ca4cec5e2e/test/test_pty.py

Answer (score 10):

If you are running Linux you can use the [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) command for this, like so:

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

When the command runs, it will inform you of which serial ports it has created. On my machine this looks like:

```
2014/04/23 15:47:49 socat[31711] N PTY is /dev/pts/12
2014/04/23 15:47:49 socat[31711] N PTY is /dev/pts/13
2014/04/23 15:47:49 socat[31711] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [3,3] and [5,5]
```

Now I can write to `/dev/pts/13` and receive on `/dev/pts/12`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to emulate an arbitrary serial port `./foo` using this code:

SerialEmulator.py

```
import os, subprocess, serial, time

# this script lets you emulate a serial device
# the client program should use the serial port file specifed by client_port

# if the port is a location that the user can't access (ex: /dev/ttyUSB0 often),
# sudo is required

class SerialEmulator(object):
    def __init__(self, device_port='./ttydevice', client_port='./ttyclient'):
        self.device_port = device_port
        self.client_port = client_port
        cmd=['/usr/bin/socat','-d','-d','PTY,link=%s,raw,echo=0' %
                self.device_port, 'PTY,link=%s,raw,echo=0' % self.client_port]
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.serial = serial.Serial(self.device_port, 9600, rtscts=True, dsrdtr=True)
        self.err = ''
        self.out = ''

    def write(self, out):
        self.serial.write(out)

    def read(self):
        line = ''
        while self.serial.inWaiting() > 0:
            line += self.serial.read(1)
        print line

    def __del__(self):
        self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        self.proc.kill()
        self.out, self.err = self.proc.communicate()
```

`socat` needs to be installed (`sudo apt-get install socat`), as well as the `pyserial` python package (`pip install pyserial`).

Open the python interpreter and import SerialEmulator:

```
>>> from SerialEmulator import SerialEmulator
>>> emulator = SerialEmulator('./ttydevice','./ttyclient') 
>>> emulator.write('foo')
>>> emulator.read()
```

Your client program can then wrap `./ttyclient` with pyserial, creating the virtual serial port.  You could also make client_port `/dev/ttyUSB0` or similar if you can't modify client code, but might need `sudo`.

Also be aware of this issue: [Pyserial does not play well with virtual port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831131/pyserial-does-not-play-well-with-virtual-port)

Comment: Do you have this code somewhere on GitHub? Why do I need to have 'ttydevice' and 'ttyclient'? I want to have a python program(device emulator) that I will run as a separate process. it will create './ttymydevice' and will reply to my serial commands as it is a really device.

Answer (score 6):

It may be easier to using something like [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) (if you're on Windows) to set up a virtual serial port, and develop on that.

Comment: is there a free `com0com` alternative (with API) that I can use in my commercial software `as it is` ? I just need the user to have virtual serial ports

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a loop device will do the job if you need to test your application without access to a device. It's included in pySerial 2.5 https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/url_handlers.html#loop

Answer (score 4):

It depends a bit on what you're trying to accomplish now...

You could wrap access to the serial port in a class and write an implementation to use socket I/O or file I/O. Then write your serial I/O class to use the same interface and plug it in when the device is available. (This is actually a good design for testing functionality without requiring external hardware.)

Or, if you are going to use the serial port for a command line interface, you could use stdin/stdout.

Or, there's this other answer about [virtual serial devices for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187/virtual-serial-port-for-linux).

Comment: Yes, write a "virtual serial device" class that duplicates the pySerial interface. Then your code can use either your "virtual device" class, or the real pySerial interface, interchangeably.

Comment: This is a good implementation since it is rather easy to implement and it will work on all platforms!

Comment: Sorry to update this old post, but could you please elaborate a bit more? This would be very helpful for me. Thanks