# Using OSX virtual serial ports with Python

Tags: python, macos, serial-port

I have a python program that currently reads JSON over bluetooth or usb serial ports and then does some stuff with it.

I want to write another python program that writes to a serial port like a bluetooth or usb device would so I can do some easy testing.

The most success I've found is from this answer [Virtual Serial Device in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291772/virtual-serial-device-in-python)
but I can't find a way to make this work between separate programs

Can anyone provide example code for two separate Python programs that communicate over virtual serial ports?

Comment: please show what you tried, and explain what happened/did not work/what problems you face.