# continuously updating graph in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pyserial

I have the following python code (in PyCharm) that I use to take readings from an `Arduino` board. The readings themselves are fine. I have the two following problems with the tkinter part of the code:

1. The code begins to read in values from Arduino as soon as it is
   launched, whereas I want to initiate this on a button click
   ('read_data'); as long as I don't press the 'read_data' button, the
   graph is not displayed, but readings are taken; I can see that when
   I open the graph several seconds after I begin running the code;
2. When I close the plot `close_plot`, the graph window is indeed
   closed, only to be re-opened a short while later.

I think the problem lies in `Top.after` as it is continuously run within the `mainloop()` and, therefore, the `read_data` function is continuously updated. How can I get around this?

```
import serial
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Top = Tk()

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

x = []
y = []

def read_data():
    plt.ion()
    new_value = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    if new_value == '':
        pass
    else:
        y.append(eval(new_value[:-2]))
        x.append(len(y) - 1)
        plt.plot(x, y, 'r-')
        plt.show()
        plt.pause(0.0001)
        Top.after(100, read_data)

def close_plot():
    plt.close()
    global x, y
    x = []
    y = []

def quit():
    Top.destroy()

Button(Top, text='Read', command=read_data).pack()
Button(Top, text='Close plot', command=close_plot).pack()
Button(Top, text='Quit', command=quit).pack()

Top.after(100, read_data)
mainloop()
```

Edit: when pressing the `read_data` button, I get the following warning:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py:2445: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function specific to this GUI is implemented warnings.warn(str, mplDeprecation)
```

Comment: 1. remove `Top.after(100, read_data)` before `mainloop()` - it starts reading 100ms after program start.

Comment: BTW: read [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) . We use "Upper case names" only for class names like  `Button`, `Tk` or `Serial` but not for variables like `Top`. It makes code more readable. Even `Stackoverflow` knows this rule and uses light blue color for classes.

Comment: @furas: I am afraid your suggestion doesn't help, the code still begins reading as soon as it gets run

Comment: @DenGor What proof you have of that exactly?

Comment: @Nae the proof is the same as before - I run the code, wait a few seconds, open a graph that already contains several data points.

Comment: did you remove correct `after()` - before `mainloop()`. If you still have problem then maybe you use different code than you show in question - ie. you may have `()` in `command=read_data()`

Comment: No, furas, I did copy+paste. I removed top.after(100, read_data) just before mainloop()

Comment: Then you have someting wrong in system - because it shouldn't run it without `after` - but I can't help.

Comment: try to run it without PyCharm - maybe there is some problem with PyCharm. Or problem is with Anaconda - I tested only with standard Python installation and don't get error `"MatplotlibDeprecationWarning"`.

Comment: @furas I've just run it in Spyder. There's good news and bad news: indeed, the error is gone but the code still behaves the way I described it in the beginning even when I copy your code from here

Comment: run it without any IDE - run it normally in shell/console/terminal/cmd.exe using `python script.py`.

Comment: @furas I beg your pardon. I overlooked the initial behavior of the code - now nothing is read as long as I don't press the button. The only problem  left is the "close_plot" command

Comment: so I problem resolved :)

Comment: @DenGor What _is_ the problem with `close plot`? Below answer doesn't resolve it?

Comment: @Nae correct. When I press the button during data aquisition, the window gets closed and shortly thereafter opened again

Comment: @furas Do you have any idea what might be wrong with PyCharm?

Comment: it may have functions to display `Matplotlib` inside IDE and it can make problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the line:

```
Top.after(100, read_data)
```

that comes *immediately* before `mainloop()` like [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) suggested.

Then add `after_cancel` method to stop calling `read_data` every 100 ms, but for that to work, we need to be assigning `after` we use inside the method to a global variable first:

```
func_id = Top.after(100, read_data)
```

and then finally call `after_cancel` in `close_plot`:

```
Top.after_cancel(func_id)
```

---

Your code should be exactly like below:

```
import serial
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Top = Tk()

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

x = []
y = []
func_id = None

def read_data():
    global func_id
    plt.ion()
    new_value = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    if new_value == '':
        pass
    else:
        y.append(eval(new_value[:-2]))
        x.append(len(y) - 1)
        plt.plot(x, y, 'r-')
        plt.show()
        plt.pause(0.0001)
    func_id = Top.after(100, read_data)

def close_plot():
    global func_id
    #to no longer update the plot
    Top.after_cancel(func_id)
    plt.close()
    global x, y
    del x[:]
    del y[:]

def quit():
    Top.destroy()

Button(Top, text='Read', command=read_data).pack()
Button(Top, text='Close plot', command=close_plot).pack()
Button(Top, text='Quit', command=quit).pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: I would put `after()` outside `if/else` so it would read all time - but I can't test it.

Comment: BTW: I try to test it on Linux using `socat` to create fake serial port -like in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23255001/1832058

Comment: I appreciate your help but I can't get it working, even when I copy your code. The errors are repeated. Additionally, I get the following warning: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function specific to this GUI is implemented warnings.warn(str, mplDeprecation)

Comment: @DenGor Please append the MCVE code piece that results in that error and also post full error message too, to your question.

Comment: @DenGor Updated the answer here, now it should be working.

Comment: @Nae you are a genius! It's working! Now, could you explain what global func_id changed?

Comment: @DenGor It just ensures the `func_id` is shared among the two methods, `close_plot` and `read_data`. It needs to be present in order to be able to use `after_cancel`.