# How communicate with pty via minicom or screen?

Tags: c, linux, virtual, modem, pty

I am trying to provide an AT/Modem-like interface around some hardware.
Follwing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187/virtual-serial-port-for-linux) I have the server setting up a pty using openpty().

Now I can communicate with the server as expected with a client app that open the slave and communicates via read() and write() calls.

However I would also like to be able to use either the screen command or minicom to issue commands by hand to the slave.  However the server never seems to receive any data when trying to do this.  Is there something significant I am missing with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

So the client app works with the hardware, but minicom does not.  Very likely the client app is properly setting the baud rate and number of stop bits (at least those), and you haven't asked minicom to do the same.  You need to get those settings right.