# CAN: How to simulate the sending and receiving the message

Tags: can-bus

I am working on CAN where already the code is ready for send and receive, but now for our unit testing we use canalyzer to test the send/receive of the data.
Is there a way wherein I can test the send/receive using 2 hosts or on a same PC.

Comment: This question is far too broad. Without knowing what hardware and systems you have, nobody can answer the question. Also, it is better to ask questions that are on the border between hardware and software at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am new to CAN.How to make use of loopback? Could you please give me some idea or some data that speaks about this, it will be of great help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many USB-CAN interfaces with libraries for Linux/OSX/Windows, such as Komodo, Peak CAN etc. You can use them to perform the tests, and usually you can connect more than one to your PC and this way test it all on a single computer.

If you are using Linux, you can use virtual CAN, which allows local send/recv with socket interface. (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040212/464988) about how to set it up).