# Socket-CAN virtual bus

Tags: can-bus, socketcan

How can I create several virtual sockets and link them together to create a virtual bus?

I want to simulate an application in which many nodes communicate to each other via CAN.

Comment: Leaving a link to a very similar question: [How to create virtual CAN port on linux? (C++)
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022749/how-to-create-virtual-can-port-on-linux-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need is **cangw** tool from [can-utils](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils). Create two virtual interfaces:

```
ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
ip link add dev vcan1 type vcan
ip link set up vcan0
ip link set up vcan1
```

Create routing rule, so that all packets coming to **vcan0** will be sent to **vcan1**:

```
cangw -A -s vcan0 -d vcan1 -e
```

Listen to vcan1 in one terminal:

```
candump vcan1
```

And send packet from another terminal:

```
cansend vcan0 123#0011
```

You'll see, that **candump** will get this CAN packet:

```
vcan1  123   [2]  00 11
```

Comment: I keep getting " netlink error -95 (Operation not supported)" any ideas?

Comment: Make sure CONFIG_CAN_GW is activated in your kernel. You can compile it either as part of the kernel or as a module.

Comment: I had to load it with "modprobe can-gw"

Comment: Hi, that blog link seems to take me to an irrelevant page. Can you fix it? 
Also, I noticed that your routing rule only works in one direction, which isn't really how a bus should work. So is it correct that I should also make another routine roule in the opposite direction?

Comment: @9a3eedi I have removed the link. I haven't tried the other way around, but you can send your question to the linux-can mailing list and get an answer from cangw developers themselves.

Comment: I tried the other way around and it seems to work the way it should. But that's just a quick assessment, I don't know if there are any catches. It should be OK though