# How to create a virtual CAN network in SocketCAN in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, can-bus, socketcan

I am planning to create a virtual CAN network in Ubuntu using SocketCAN for my project. So far, I can create multiple can interface using the ip link add dev can1 type vcan command. However, I cannot get them to communicate with each other. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you already looked at [cangw](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils/blob/master/cangw.c)? You can also use one `vcan0` interface in multipple applications.

Comment: Thanks. I worked with cangw and was able to create a network using virtual can interfaces.

Comment: if you are still looking for an answere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574256/socket-can-virtual-bus