# What is the minimum hardware requirements for a CAN bus simulation?

Tags: simulation, can-bus

I am making a research about CAN bus, and I need to see how it works. Is there a way to simulate simple CAN bus instructions? What hardware I must have for this purpose?

P.S: I am very new to topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simulate `can` instructions you don't need any hardware. You can use `socketcan` under Linux and setup a [virtual can-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040212/9024797).

After you have setup the virtual can-interface `vcan0`, to try first things install `can-utils`:

```
sudo apt install can-utils
```

Then listen on the virtual can interface `vcan0` by executing

```
candump vcan0
```

On another terminal send for example a can frame (with identifier `123`) with 3 bytes of data `0x123456` to the interface `vcan0` via

```
cansend vcan0 123#123456
```

You should also see the sent can-frame on the other terminal, where you executed `candump vcan0`.

In case you really want to "talk" to a real CAN-network you need hardware. One good and cost-effective way, would be to use a Raspberry Pi with a CAN-extension shield. Also there you can use `socketcan` + `can-utils`.