# Qt and virtual serial ports

Tags: linux, qt, qtserialport

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187/virtual-serial-port-for-linux) in order to create a pair of serial ports. It works fine.

Now I'm developing a Qt app (using [QtSerialPort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-index.html)) to send data through the serial port and what I really want is such a virtual serial port link. But it appears that `QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()` cannot find the /dev/pts/... ports.

Which approach should I try in order to make such a serial port link on linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the /dev/pts are not a serial ports, and the SOCAT creates a symlinks to the /dev/pts devices. So, all correct.

But, using SOCAT it is not a good idea, because it is unstable (after re-opening and so on, in my practice). It is better to use tty0tty project instead (but, unfortunately, the QSerialPort::availablePorts() doesn't enumerate it too). But it is not a problem, because the tty0tty's serial ports can be easy fixed for QSerialPort (required a small patch).

So, currently there are no approach to enumerate this easy. Maybe on Qt 5.6 the tty0tty will be added for QSerialPort enumeration.

As workaround, you can use QDir on the /dev directory to enumerate all symlinks (of course, if you create this symlinks in /dev directory).

Comment: "unfortunately, the QSerialPort::availablePorts() doesn't enumerate it too" means I cannot even use it? I was expecting to be able to use them if explicitly telling Qt about the address. I've tried `cat < /dev/tnt1` and then in Qt, wrote data to `/dev/tnt0` but nothing was shown by the `cat` side.

Comment: "tty0tty's serial ports can be easy fixed for QSerialPort (required a small patch)", could you please tell me more about this patch?

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot even use it?

You can use any custom serial port name and to pass it to QSerialPort.

> but nothing was shown by the cat side

You can try to use the Terminal example, which is part of qtserialport examples.

> ould you please tell me more about this patch?

https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/125856/