# ttyS0 not showing on terminal

Tags: java, linux, serial-port

I want to list open serial ports in Java but I didn't do it. I'm using jssc and jSerialComm library in Java but SerialPorts is empty.

When I write in terminal `sudo dmesg | grep tty`, 
ıt's showing to me tty0  : `console [tty0] enabled`

Why I dont see ttyS0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message you see does not mean you have a serial port, it only means that the kernel messages are directed to a virtual serial port (`/dev/tty0`). See [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/serial-console.html) for more details.

Based on the output of `dmesg` on your system I'm afraid you don't have any hardware (real) serial ports. You can either go get a USB-to-serial for a couple of bucks or use `socat` to create a [virtual serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187/virtual-serial-port-for-linux).

If you do have a hardware serial port then you are most probably facing a hardware  or driver problem.