# is it possible to emulate the response of a serial port in linux?

Tags: python, pyserial

[I created a virtual serial port with based in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19733677/12824989)

So I use a python script to write and read in my serial port

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/pts/3')  
>>> print(ser.name)         
>>> ser.write(b'hello')     
>>> ser.close()
```

And this works. But when I tried to read my serial port in doesn't return anything

```
>>> with serial.Serial('/dev/pts/3') as ser:
...     x = ser.read()          
...     s = ser.read(10)        
...     line = ser.readline()
..      print(line)
```

I'm doing something wrong ? There is another way to emulate a serial port in linux ?

Comment: What happens when you print those values?

Comment: re-read the original post you linked to. Read from `pts/2` and write to `pts/3`.

Comment: yeah but I didn't get anything in pts/2 too :c

Comment: I read in pts/2, but is stuck https://imgur.com/a/zyNqfbf

Comment: You are closing `pts/3` before reading on `pts/2`. Just don't do that, if you close the port its buffers are emptied. Keep both ports open and it'll work