# C++ serial communication under same host machine

Tags: c++, linux, serialization, serial-communication

Is there a way for two C++ applications to send/receive message to/from each other by under same host machine using serial communication ?
p/s: I am having a Linux-based environment

Comment: Do you mean COM port serial or just serial as in a stream of bytes?  For a stream of bytes look into Pipes.

Comment: Have you tried `termios`?

Comment: @RichardCritten yes COM port serial

Comment: @Antonio I haven't. I have had a quick search over the Internet and yes I saw some ppl are using termios. Probably I should start looking at this

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187/virtual-serial-port-for-linux) may be of some help.  Specifically the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187/virtual-serial-port-for-linux/19733677#19733677).