# *Bit-level* virtual serial port for Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, emulation, virtual-serial-port

There are [virtual serial port implementations for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187/virtual-serial-port-for-linux) but they all seem to be higher-level than the actual hardware reality of something like UART. What I'd like to do is to create a virtual serial port that is connected to a process that uses two single-bit channels for transmission and reception. The context of this is interactive testing of simulated circuitry, e.g. taking an FPGA configuration in Verilog that has a serial port, compiling it with Verilator into a native executable, and then communicating it through a virtual serial port.

Comment: Perhaps this site is not suitable for your question. How about moving to this site? [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: How fine is the time granularity/resolution required? Does that determine whether it can be handled by Linux software that is not a real-time system?

Comment: @kunif: that is a good question. Something in the order of magnitude of 9600 bps should be doable?

Comment: Those who can answer it are those who have experience and knowledge, and I cannot give a valid answer. In that sense, it would be better to change the site that asks questions. However, from my poor knowledge, 9600bps should only allow 100 microseconds per bit. Even the low-level layers of device drivers are likely to require the assistance of dedicated hardware to sample data at precise intervals and buffer the sampled data.