# Boost::Asio not able to configure Windows & Linux serial port structures using native handle

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am working on serial port routines using Boost::Asio.
I am configuring the port using the wrappers provided by Boost::Asio.
In my application either the end of data is denoted by receive timeout or `\r\n` line termination sequence.
As Boost::Asio doesn't provide wrapper to access and configure `DCB` - Windows, `termios` - Linux structure in order to configure timeout and/or line-ending; I am accessing native port handle/file descriptor that is returned via the `native_handle` wrapper and configuring the structures manually.
However it seems I am unable to configure the port properly.
Even if I configure the end of data to be denoted by `\n` the data is partially returned in chunks.
Similarly the data is also returned before timeout has occurred.

---

**Update**

The system works in 2 modes

1. Line Mode -> The data is read line by line and the processed. Line ending characters `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`.
2. Bulk Mode -> Multi-line data is read. Once no data is received for pre-dertmined interval, the data is said to be completely received. e.g. If I don't receive new data for 50 milli-seconds I consider the transfer to be complete.

---

Code

```
bool SerialPort::open_port(void)
{
    try
    {
        this->port.open(this->port_name);
        this->native_port = this->port.native_handle();
        return true;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        PLOG_FATAL << ex.what();
    }
    return false;
}

bool SerialPort::open_port(const std::string& port_name, std::uint32_t baud_rate, std::uint8_t data_bits, std::uint8_t stop_bits,
    parity_t parity, flow_control_t flow_control, std::uint32_t read_timeout, std::uint32_t read_inter_byte_timeout,
    std::uint32_t write_timeout)
{
    try
    {
        this->port_name = port_name;
        if (not this->open_port())
            return false;
        if (not this->set_baud_rate(baud_rate).has_value())
            return false;
        if (not this->set_data_bits(data_bits).has_value())
            return false;
        if (not this->set_stop_bits(stop_bits).has_value())
            return false;
        if (not this->set_parity(parity).has_value())
            return false;
        if (not this->set_flow_control(flow_control).has_value())
            return false;
        this->read_timeout = read_timeout;
        if (read_inter_byte_timeout <= 0)
            this->read_inter_byte_timeout = 1;

#ifdef _WIN64
        BOOL            return_value;
        DCB             dcb = { 0 };
        COMMTIMEOUTS    timeouts = { 0 };
        if (this->line_mode)    //Set COM port to return data either at \n or \r
        {
            /*
            * If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
            * If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
            */
            return_value = GetCommState(this->native_port, &dcb);
            if (return_value)
            {
                if(this->new_line_character == '\r')
                    dcb.EofChar = '\r'; //Specify end of data character as carriage-return (\r)
                else // --> Default
                    dcb.EofChar = '\n'; //Specify end of data character as new-line (\n) 
            }
            else
            {
                PLOG_ERROR << "Error GetCommState : " << GetLastErrorAsString();
                return false;
            }
            /*
            * If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
            * If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
            */
            return_value = SetCommState(this->native_port, &dcb);
            if (not return_value)
            {
                PLOG_ERROR << "Error SetCommState : " << GetLastErrorAsString();
                return false;
            }
        }
        else    //Set COM port to return data on timeout
        {
            /*
            * If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
            * If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
            */
            return_value = GetCommTimeouts(this->native_port, &timeouts);
            if (return_value)
            {
                timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = this->read_inter_byte_timeout; // Timeout in miliseconds
                //timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;   //MAXDWORD; // in milliseconds - not needed
                //timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0; // in milliseconds - not needed
                //timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50; // in milliseconds - not needed
                //timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = write_timeout; // in milliseconds - not needed
            }
            else
            {
                PLOG_ERROR << "Error GetCommTimeouts : " << GetLastErrorAsString();
                return false;
            }
            /*
            * If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
            * If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
            */
            return_value = SetCommTimeouts(this->native_port, &timeouts);
            if (not return_value)
            {
                PLOG_ERROR << "Error SetCommTimeouts : " << GetLastErrorAsString();
                return false;
            }
        }
#else //For Linux termios
#endif // _WIN64

        return true;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        PLOG_ERROR << ex.what();
        return false;
    }
}

void SerialPort::read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    this->read_async(); // I realized I was calling read_async before reading data
    bool receive_complete{ false };
    try
    {
        if (error not_eq boost::system::errc::success)  //Error in serial port read
        {
            PLOG_ERROR << error.to_string();
            this->async_signal.emit(this->port_number, SerialPortEvents::read_error, error.to_string());
            return;
        }

        if (this->line_mode)
        {
            std::string temporary_recieve_data;
            std::transform(this->read_buffer.begin(), this->read_buffer.begin() + bytes_transferred, //Data is added to temporary buffer
                std::back_inserter(temporary_recieve_data), [](std::byte character) {
                    return static_cast<char>(character);
                }
            );
            boost::algorithm::trim(temporary_recieve_data); // Trim handles space character, tab, carriage return, newline, vertical tab and form feed
            //Data is further processed based on the Process logic
            receive_complete = true;
        }
        else    // Bulk-Data. Just append data to end of received_data string buffer.
                // Wait for timeout to trigger recevive_complete
        {
            //Test Function
            std::transform(this->read_buffer.begin(), this->read_buffer.begin() + bytes_transferred,
                std::back_inserter(this->received_data), [](std::byte character) {
                    return static_cast<char>(character);
                }
            );
            this->async_signal.emit(this->port_number, SerialPortEvents::read_data, this->received_data); //Data has been recieved send to server via MQTT
        }
            
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        PLOG_ERROR << ex.what();
        this->async_signal.emit(this->port_number, SerialPortEvents::read_error, ex.what());
    }
}
```

---

Supporting Function

```
std::optional<std::uint32_t> SerialPort::set_baud_rate(std::uint32_t baud_rate)
{
    boost::system::error_code                   error;
    std::uint32_t                               _baud_rate = 1200;
    switch (baud_rate)
    {
    case 1200:
    case 2400:
    case 4800:
    case 9600:
    case 115200:
        _baud_rate = baud_rate;
        break;
    default:
        _baud_rate = 1200;
        break;
    }

    this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(_baud_rate), error);

    if (error)
    {
        PLOG_FATAL << error.message();
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    return baud_rate;
}

std::optional<std::uint8_t> SerialPort::set_data_bits(std::uint8_t data_bits)
{
    boost::system::error_code                   error;
    std::uint32_t                               _data_bits = 8;
    switch (data_bits)
    {
    case 7:
    case 8:
        _data_bits = data_bits;
        break;
    default:
        _data_bits = 8;
        break;
    }

    this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size(_data_bits), error);

    if (error)
    {
        PLOG_FATAL << error.message();
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    return data_bits;
}

std::optional<std::uint8_t> SerialPort::set_stop_bits(std::uint8_t stop_bits)
{
    boost::system::error_code                   error;
    switch (stop_bits)
    {
    case 1:
        this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one), error);
        break;
    case 2:
        this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::two), error);
        break;
    default:
        this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one), error);
        break;
    }

    if (error)
    {
        PLOG_FATAL << error.message();
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    return stop_bits;
}


std::optional<parity_t> SerialPort::set_parity(parity_t parity)
{
    boost::system::error_code                   error;
    switch (parity)
    {
    case Parity::none:
        this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::none), error);
        break;
    case Parity::even:
        this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::even), error);
        break;
    case Parity::odd:
        this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::odd), error);
        break;
    default:
        this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::none), error);
        break;
    }

    if (error)
    {
        PLOG_FATAL << error.message();
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    return parity;
}

std::optional<flow_control_t> SerialPort::set_flow_control(flow_control_t flow_control)
{
    boost::system::error_code                   error;
    switch (flow_control)
    {
    case FlowControl::none:
        this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::none), error);
        break;
    case FlowControl::hardware:
        this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::hardware), error);
        break;
    case FlowControl::software:
        this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::software), error);
        break;
    default:
        this->port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::none), error);
        break;
    }

    if (error)
    {
        PLOG_FATAL << error.message();
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    return flow_control;
}
```

Comment: DCB.EofChar does no such thing.

Comment: @HansPassant; I got the reference from the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-dcb. Third last entry is `EofChar`.

Comment: https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.18.0/doc/asio/reference/read_until.html

Comment: @HansPassant Isn't `read_until` synchronous in nature? The second problem I have with `read_until` is that I won't be able to run the function on timeout as I do when `this->line_mode` is `false`.

Comment: @DarkSorrow I'm sure [async_read_until](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.18.0/doc/asio/reference/async_read_until.html) isn't. I don't understand your claim w.r.t. timeouts. Why don't you ask /that/ as a question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @sehe, Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question. The system operates in 2 modes line mode and bulk mode, which are separated by if statement as mentioned in the code. In bulk mode the incoming data is multi-line hence I have set read timeout inetrval in the serial port structures.

Comment: @sehe I have been looking into `boost::asio::async_read_until( this->port, 
    boost::asio::buffer(this->read_buffer.data(), this->read_buffer.size()), 
    this->new_line_character,
    boost::bind(
     &SerialPort::read_handler, 
     this, 
     boost::asio::placeholders::error, 
     boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
    )
   );` but I am getting `E0304 no instance of overloaded function "boost::asio::async_read_until" matches the argument list` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your comments:

> the incoming data is multi-line hence I have set read timeout inetrval in the serial port structures

How does that make sense. There's no real difference handling timeouts in Asio either way/

Regarding the overload:

> but I am getting E0304    no instance of overloaded function "boost::asio::async_read_until" matches the argument list error.

Here's my ten pence:

```
async_read_until(port,
    asio::dynamic_buffer(read_buffer),
    "\r\n",
    bind(&SerialPort::read_handler, this, error, bytes_transferred));
```

Note that you need dynamic buffers. The simplest thing I could think of that stays [close to your original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74661374/85371):

```
std::vector<std::byte> read_buffer;
```

Now, we'll update the read handler to erase the "consumed" part, because received buffer may contain data beyond the delimiter.

```
void read_handler(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t const bytes_transferred) {
    std::cerr << "received " << bytes_transferred << " bytes (" << ec.message() << ")"
              << std::endl;

    auto b = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(read_buffer.data()),
         e = b + std::min(bytes_transferred, read_buffer.size());

    if (std::all_of(
            b, e,                                                             //
            [](uint8_t ch) { return std::isspace(ch) || std::isgraph(ch); })) //
    {
        std::cerr << "ascii: " << quoted(std::string_view(b, e)) << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "binary: ";
        auto fmt = std::cerr.flags();
        for (auto it = b; it != e; ++it) {
            std::cerr << " " << std::hex << std::showbase << std::setfill('0')
                      << std::setw(4) << static_cast<unsigned>(*it);
        }
        std::cerr.flags(fmt);
    }
    std::cerr << std::endl;

    read_buffer.erase(begin(read_buffer), begin(read_buffer) + bytes_transferred);

    if (!ec)
        read_async(ignore_timeout);
}
```

Full listing: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5250b96e9ff0e306)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

static inline std::ostream PLOG_ERROR(std::cerr.rdbuf());

struct SerialPort {
    static constexpr uint32_t ignore_timeout = -1;

    SerialPort(asio::any_io_executor ex, std::string dev) : port(ex, dev) {}

    bool read_async(uint32_t timeout_override) {
        try {
            // not necessary: std::ranges::fill(read_buffer, std::byte{});

            if (timeout_override not_eq SerialPort::ignore_timeout) {
                read_timeout = timeout_override;
            }
            using namespace asio::placeholders;

            async_read_until(port,
                asio::dynamic_buffer(read_buffer),
                "\r\n",
                bind(&SerialPort::read_handler, this, error, bytes_transferred));

            return true;
        } catch (std::exception const& ex) {
            PLOG_ERROR << ex.what() << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

  private:
    void read_handler(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t const bytes_transferred) {
        std::cerr << "received " << bytes_transferred << " bytes (" << ec.message() << ")"
                  << std::endl;

        auto b = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(read_buffer.data()),
             e = b + std::min(bytes_transferred, read_buffer.size());

        if (std::all_of(
                b, e,                                                             //
                [](uint8_t ch) { return std::isspace(ch) || std::isgraph(ch); })) //
        {
            std::cerr << "ascii: " << quoted(std::string_view(b, e)) << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "binary: ";
            auto fmt = std::cerr.flags();
            for (auto it = b; it != e; ++it) {
                std::cerr << " " << std::hex << std::showbase << std::setfill('0')
                          << std::setw(4) << static_cast<unsigned>(*it);
            }
            std::cerr.flags(fmt);
        }
        std::cerr << std::endl;

        read_buffer.erase(begin(read_buffer), begin(read_buffer) + bytes_transferred);

        if (!ec)
            read_async(ignore_timeout);
    }

    uint32_t               read_timeout = 10;
    std::vector<std::byte> read_buffer;
    asio::serial_port      port;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    asio::io_context ioc;

    SerialPort sp(make_strand(ioc), argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "/dev/ttyS0");
    sp.read_async(SerialPort::ignore_timeout);

    ioc.run();
}
```

Local demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked. For multiline termination based on receive timeout I am using `system_timer`. Can you help me understand why configuring Windows's serial port structure after extracting native handle didn't configure the serial port (line termination sequence or receive timeout.

Comment: What is "multiline termination"? Either you have data framing or you don't. Framing "whatever arrives in n milliseconds" can be done with any producer/consumer combination.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your question about configuration. I'm not even convinced your observation or expectations are correct, but I may not be qualified to judge that anyways.

Comment: In `bulk mode` aka.` multi-line data` i.e. when `if (this->line_mode)` is `false`, I don't know how many bytes will be received in that particular transfer or what will be the end of transmission character e.g. `\r\n` . In such case I use timeout capability of serial port driver i.e. if no new data is received for n milliseconds, regard as transfer is complete and being processing received data.

Comment: As for the for serial port in `DCB` or `termios` structure, I'm using the same proven code that is currently running in my application. The only unknown part is creating/opening handle/file descriptor using Boost::Asio insead of native Win32/Linux system call.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure you need non-portable things: [simplified code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/455a6cf4bbef8f80) - live demo of timings https://i.imgur.com/zsWLWAc.gif