# localhost-like environment for Modbus RTU on Linux

Tags: modbus, pymodbus, modbus-rtu-over-tcp

I have been working with Modbus lately to communicate with some solar inverters and batteries. I am working on creating a virtual environment where I can test some basic operation of my code without needing to test everything on the physical system.

I am using the pymodbus library and used the server_async.py example to create a virtual Modbus TCP slave (server) on localhost (IP 0.0.0.0, port 502).

Is there a way I can do the same for Modbus RTU ?

I am working on an Ubuntu 22.04 OS.

Comment: Modbus RTU is binary Modbus protocol over serial link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus#Modbus_RTU

The protocol is quite simple so it should be doable using virtual serial port: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187/virtual-serial-port-for-linux